# Business Workflow Software

Tags: c#, sql, process

Any recommends here? I need something that can take a set of processes and batch them together. For example, I need to:

1) execute some sql

2) run C# snippets

3) have checkpoint steps with human interaction (i.e. send off an email at step X and wait for a user to review a result and click continue etc...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using C#, you might as well use the Windows Workflow Framework that's part of 3.5.  That is pretty much exactly what it's used for.

Answer (score -1):

I use Captaris Workflow for that. Quite expensive but it works really well.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on how much you're willing to code vs how much you're willing to pay.  You *could* code it all in "plain" .NET code for "free".  Next step up would be using Windows Workflow, though you'd still need to code the "human interaction" steps.  Slightly more expensive would be a tool like FinalBuilder or Automiser, which would mean less code for you to write, and a more visual workflow designer.  Even more expensive- but allowing for potentially no code- would be an enterprise system like BizTalk, MetaStorm, K2, etc.